# strncat Wformat-overflow warning when using gcc 8.2.1

Tags: c++, string, gcc, gcc-warning, gcc8

I'm using gcc 8.2.1 and trying to build this code:

```
std::string dir = "Documents";
char * _tempname = static_cast <char*> (malloc( dir.length() + 14));
strncpy (_tempname, dir.c_str(), dir.length()+1 );
strncat (_tempname, "/hellooXXXXXX", 13);
```

but it gives me this warning:

> warning: `'char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)'` specified bound
>   13 equals source length [-Wstringop-overflow=]

After searching I found that it's an overflow problem to have the size_t equals the source length according to the discussion in this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83007#c1) but I couldn't understand why this is considered a problem and why this overflows the destination. And how could I remove this warning without changing my code?

Comment: `strncat` expects a C-string as a first argument, but you're passing some uninitialized char array to it. Also why you're allocating memory manually when you could simply do `std::string tempname = dir + "/hellooXXXXXX"`?

Comment: I forgot a line of code and I edited it now sorry, regarding the code why I'm not using string, actually I'm maintaining this code not writing it from scratch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently GCC understands that `strncat(_tempname, "/hellooXXXXXX", 13);` is no different from `strcat(_tempname, "/hellooXXXXXX");`, and finds it suspicious that you're using former instead of the latter.

If you can change the code, use `strcat` instead (or even better, rewrite the thing to use `std::string`).

If you can't change the code, use `-Wno-stringop-overflow` flag to disable the warning.

Answer (score 3):

my understanding is that gcc issues this warning only because it's a common mistake for users to set the bound equal to the src length, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The function expects the space left in the destination not the length of the source string, so use

```
// ...
strncat(_tempname, "/hellooXXXXXX", dir.length() + 14 - strlen(_tempname) - 1);`
```

instead. No, forget that. Use `std::string` instead.