# Booting xv6 with qemu

Tags: operating-system, qemu, xv6

I am trying to boot xv6 with qemu but whenever I run `make qemu` , I am getting the following error

```
usertests.c: In function ‘sbrktest’:
usertests.c:1461:13: error: writing 1 byte into a region of size 0 [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
 1461 |   *lastaddr = 99;
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [<builtin>: usertests.o] Error 1
```

Running `make qemu-nox` resulted in same error.I am using `Kubuntu 21.10` operating system.[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/p4445x/help_xv6_installation_on_manjaro/) is a way around but I am looking for a solution if anyone finds out.

Comment: add CFLAGS ` -Wno-stringop-overflow`
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408543/strncat-wformat-overflow-warning-when-using-gcc-8-2-1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would help:
Delete "_usertests" & "usertests.c" from makefile and try make clean - > make -> make qemu

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem just now, don't use the higher version ubuntu. I make qemu-nox success in 18.04 ubuntu operation system.